# LogCat is absent in Android Studio at not Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, logcat

In the context of IONIC based application, I am developing a Native Cordova plugin for Android. I opened the Android prepared and run the application by Android Studio successfully. But I see that LogCat has gone away from everywhere: menu, actions ... But it is working for the bare project generated by Android Studio. And I reuse it. But it weird. I see that LogCat is not tangled to the project. It has to be available everywhere. I need it. I've attached my plugin and I do not see my notifications tagged. It is the issue of the next question ...

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but if you need LogCat, but your IDE cannot display it, you can always use a simple temrinal/command line for it:

`adb logcat`

this command will give you a tailed logcat in your terminal.

Just to make sure: The logcat is generated on the mobile device! Not on your computer! Android Studio is reading it from the device to show it.

If Android Studio is not showing it, you can either try to hide/show it using the `Alt + 6` shortcut or you can try reconnecting your device by:

- either just pulling the USB cable and reconnect it
- or restart the adb server with the two commands `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`
- or by clicking on the restart icon in the Logcat window of AndroidStudio (see image attached)

[image]

Comment: Yes, partly. But it is a console. I would like it at Android Studio.

Comment: I added more information that may help. see the edited answer